# Mysql query sum another column with a condition

Tags: mysql

this is my first question so I hope that I don't mess it up.

Here's a SQL Fiddle I made to help me explain it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f2b5c/7

We have questions, answers, question_types and answer_types.

I want to know for each question, how many people have answered each answer_type and how many people have answered that question, but I'm unable to get the total.

This is what I'm getting:

```
id | fk_question_type | description            | num | value      | total
1  | 1                | How was the breakfast? | 0   | Bad        | 0
1  | 1                | How was the breakfast? | 1   | Good       | 1
1  | 1                | How was the breakfast? | 0   | Indifferent| 0
1  | 1                | How was the breakfast? | 2   | Very good  | 2
2  | 1                | How was the lunch?     | 0   | Bad        | 0
2  | 1                | How was the lunch?     | 1   | Good       | 1
2  | 1                | How was the lunch?     | 0   | Indifferent| 1
2  | 1                | How was the lunch?     | 1   | Very good  | 1
```

This is what I'd like:

```
id | fk_question_type | description            | num | value      | total
1  | 1                | How was the breakfast? | 0   | Bad        | 3
1  | 1                | How was the breakfast? | 1   | Good       | 3
1  | 1                | How was the breakfast? | 0   | Indifferent| 3
1  | 1                | How was the breakfast? | 2   | Very good  | 3
2  | 1                | How was the lunch?     | 0   | Bad        | 2
2  | 1                | How was the lunch?     | 1   | Good       | 2
2  | 1                | How was the lunch?     | 0   | Indifferent| 2
2  | 1                | How was the lunch?     | 1   | Very good  | 2
```

The query I'm trying right now:

```
SELECT id, fk_question_type, description, num, value, SUM(num) AS totalAnswers
FROM (
    (SELECT q.id, q.fk_question_type, q.description, COUNT(a.id) AS num, at.value
    FROM answer a 
    LEFT JOIN question q ON a.`fk_question`=q.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN answer_type at ON at.id = a.`fk_answer_type` 
    GROUP BY q.id, at.id  ORDER BY q.id, at.id)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT q.id, q.fk_question_type, q.description, 0 AS num, at.value
    FROM answer a 
    LEFT JOIN question q ON a.`fk_question`=q.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN answer_type at ON at.fk_question_type=q.fk_question_type
    GROUP BY q.id, at.id  ORDER BY q.id, at.id)
) AS T 
WHERE fk_question_type = 1
GROUP BY id, value ORDER BY id
```

How can I SUM the num for the rows with the same id while keeping the other columns?

Comment: Do you really need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`? Can you really have an answer without a corresponding question?

Comment: From table `answers` in the fiddle, it can be seen that questions `How was breakfast?`, `How was lunch?` and `Would you come again?` were asked three times each. `How was dinner` was only asked twice. With that being noted, could you please elaborate on what you want to see in `num` and what in `total`?

Comment: @DhruvSaxena I want `num` to be how it already is, `How was breakfast?` was answered with a `Bad` value 0 times, 1 time as `Good`, 0 times as `Indifferent` and 2 times as `Very good`. `Total` should be how many times the question was answered, so that's 3 times for each row of `How was breakfast?`
Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the total for each `id`, and join that with the query that gets the per-value rows.

And in the outer query, you should use `SUM(num)` or `MAX(num)` to combine the `num` values from the two queries in the `UNION`.

```
SELECT T.id, fk_question_type, description, SUM(num) AS num, value, T2.totalAnswers
FROM (
    (SELECT q.id, q.fk_question_type, q.description, COUNT(a.id) AS num, at.value
    FROM answer a 
    LEFT JOIN question q ON a.`fk_question`=q.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN answer_type at ON at.id = a.`fk_answer_type` 
    GROUP BY q.id, at.id  ORDER BY q.id, at.id)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT q.id, q.fk_question_type, q.description, 0 AS num, at.value
    FROM answer a 
    LEFT JOIN question q ON a.`fk_question`=q.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN answer_type at ON at.fk_question_type=q.fk_question_type
    GROUP BY q.id, at.id  ORDER BY q.id, at.id)
) AS T 
JOIN (SELECT q.id, COUNT(*) AS totalAnswers
      FROM answer a 
      LEFT JOIN question q ON a.`fk_question`=q.`id` 
      LEFT JOIN answer_type at ON at.id = a.`fk_answer_type` 
      GROUP BY q.id) AS t2 ON T.id = T2.id
WHERE fk_question_type = 1
GROUP BY T.id, value
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f2b5c/20)